# Simple healthcheck endpoint in kong gateway

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, kongregate

I have a docker container running with kong gateway.

I want to provide a rest interface/endpoint to check the health of the server and container. E.g. GET http://container.com/health/ which delivers
200 OK
'{"status":"UP"}';

What is the simplest and quickest solution or best practice?

Comment: https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/how-kong-works/health-checks/ can be good place to see. If you have specific definition of healthy then you can implement the service on the application side and then put kong in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a /health route and enable the request-termination plugin like so:

```
routes:
- name: health
  paths:
  - /health
  plugins:
  - name: request-termination
    config:
     status_code: 200
     content_type: application/json
     body: '{"status":"UP"}'
```

That being said, the preferred way of determining the health status of a Kong node is to actually use the built-in health routes (/status endpoint):

https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/admin-api/#health-routes